# Error: cannot get the transaction for "Contract Name" previous deployment, please check your node synced status

Tags: solidity, hardhat, ganache

For some reason when I was retrying to redeploy my contracts to ganache, this error

> Error: cannot get the transaction for "Contract Name" previous deployment, please check your node synced status.

showed up.

I was working with moralis, then closed my system, reset the blockchain on moralis, and ganache to redo everything.

After that, I retried deploying the contract the above error showed up.
I am not sure if the above condition are the only reason for this error, but for my case here's how I solved it.

Answer (score 3):

In your main folder, there would be a deployments folder where information about all your deployed contracts will reside.

Go to that folder, in my case it's `Project/deployments/` and then you will see many other folders for all your deployments ex localhost, ganache.

In my case, it was ganache. Under that you will find deployed `.json` files for each of your contracts.

DELETE THEM.

And retry deploying again.